# Is there any way to get the html formed when XSL manipulates XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, servlets

I'm using java servlet so that my user can submit an xml file which is sent to a server which holds a static xsl file inside the WEB-INF folder. When the user presses submit, they are presented their xml information in a neat html format. I was wondering if it is possible to grab the html that is formed through the transformation so that the user can download it for their own record keeping. However, even right-clicking and inspecting source just gives me the raw xml data.

Comment: One way is to press CTRL-A to select the whole content and then use the right click option `View Source` to get the HTML.

Comment: I tried that already and it just gives me xml